# Error:In <declare-styleable> SherlockSpinner, unable to find attribute android:popupPromptView

Tags: android, gradle, actionbarsherlock, pull-to-refresh

My project contains "ActionBar Sherlock Pull to refresh" and compiles and runs fine with API level 21 and earlier but when i am trying to compile it with API 22, i'm getting this error:

```
Error:In <declare-styleable> SherlockSpinner, unable to find attribute android:popupPromptView
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
```

> com.android.ide.common.internal.LoggedErrorException: Failed to run command:
>       /Users/m./Android_SDK/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt package -f --no-crunch -I /Users/m./Android_SDK/platforms/android-22/android.jar -M /Users/m./AndroidStudioProjects/-android/android/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml -S /Users/m./AndroidStudioProjects/-android/android/build/intermediates/res/debug -A /Users/m./AndroidStudioProjects/-android/android/build/intermediates/assets/debug -m -J /Users/m./AndroidStudioProjects/-android/android/build/generated/source/r/debug -F /Users/m./AndroidStudioProjects/-android/android/build/intermediates/res/resources-debug.ap_ --debug-mode --custom-package ir.fax.android -0 apk --output-text-symbols /Users/m./AndroidStudioProjects/-android/android/build/intermediates/symbols/debug
>     Error Code:
>       1
>     Output:
>       warning: string 'dashboard_account_type_click_msg_1' has no default translation.
>       warning: string 'dashboard_number_click_msg_1' has no default translation.
>       warning: string 'dashboard_number_click_msg_2' has no default translation.
>       warning: string 'dashboard_number_click_msg_3' has no default translation.
>       warning: string 'days_after' has no default translation.
>       warning: string 'days_before' has no default translation.
>       warning: string 'extra_cred_response' has no default translation.
>       warning: string 'free_pages_remaining_server_response' has no default translation.
>       warning: string 'hours_after' has no default translation.
>       warning: string 'hours_before' has no default translation.
>       warning: string 'invalid' has no default translation.
>       warning: string 'invit1' has no default translation.
>       warning: string 'invit2' has no default translation.
>       warning: string 'invit25' has no default translation.
>       warning: string 'invit3' has no default translation.
>       warning: string 'minutes_after' has no default translation.
>       warning: string 'minutes_before' has no default translation.
>       warning: string 'seconds_after' has no default translation.
>       warning: string 'seconds_before' has no default translation.
>       warning: string 'total_page_remaining_response' has no default translation.
>       ERROR: In  SherlockSpinner, unable to find attribute android:popupPromptView

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Solution if you are using gradle :

```
android {
  compileSdkVersion 22
  buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
[...]
}
```

If you are using an android projet in Eclipse : upgrade the build tools version to 22.0.1 in the SDK manager.

Cause of the problem :

/Users/m./Android_SDK/build-tools/**21.1.2**
should match
/Users/m./Android_SDK/platforms/**android-22**

I had the same problem after I downloaded android SDK platform 22. Upgrading the build tools to 22.0.1 fixed it.

Comment: Which one can be higher than the other?

Comment: What is sure is that the build tools version should never be higher than the platform version. I don't know if the other way is supposed to work or not. If it is, then there is a bug somewhere in the combination "ABS + build-tools 21.1.2 + android-22". Did you try to upgrade the build tools ?