# Is it mandatory to compile my app with api 22 lollipop?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, compiler-errors

My project compiles and runs fine with api 21 and when i try to compile it with api 22 i'm facing many errors from gradle ([Error:In <declare-styleable> SherlockSpinner, unable to find attribute android:popupPromptView](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29726125/3248593), and many other errors) and i can't fix them.

So the question is what happens if i let api 22 go and just compile it with api 21, and which devices can't run my app?

**UPDATE:**

Please take a look at my config and tell me which devices can't run my app
this is a part of my build.gradle config file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 9
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
        checkReleaseBuilds false
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:6.5.+'
    compile project(':chipsLibrary')
    compile project(':slidingMenu')
    compile project(':listviewanims')
    compile project(':switchCompatLibrary')
    compile project(':lib_numberpicker')
    compile project(':styleddialogslib')
    compile project(':doomDatePickerlibrary')
    compile project(':swipelistview')
    compile project(':actionbarsherlockPullToRefresh')
    compile project(':showcaseLib_Untouched_library')
    compile project(':cropper')
    compile project(':library_androidanims')
    compile project(':library_async_45')
    compile files('libs/google-api-services-drive-v2-rev123-1.18.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-oauth-client-1.18.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/acra-4.5.0.jar')
    // Required for Dropbox
    compile files('libs/dropbox-android-sdk-1.6.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/json_simple-1.1.jar')
    compile files('libs/systembartint-1.0.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.9.2 (1).jar')
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-api-client-1.18.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-api-client-android-1.18.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-1.18.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-android-1.18.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/google-http-client-gson-1.18.0-rc.jar')
    compile files('libs/joda-time-2.3.jar')
    compile files('libs/itext-4.2.1.jar')
}
```

Comment: It is not a must and devices with 22 vers can run it also but may lack some of the feqturea exposed by 22nd

Comment: Its your choice for compile on which api level, choose max and min api level that way. Or you can download latest API 22 and make emulator with this then compile.

Comment: Devices <= api 9 and >= api 19 will not be able to install/run your app.

Comment: Add your error stack

Comment: what should i do to include api 22 devices and not facing errors?

Comment: Set your target to 22 and i guess you are missing dependencies,

Comment: i've added them already!

Comment: You should also upgrade your build tools. I had the same kind of problem and upgrading the build tools to 22.0.1 fixed it.

Comment: Strange...I had the same problem and the issue was that I was using api level 22. Changing to 21 solved the problem for the moment.

Comment: This error looks, due to style used in popup, try to find in which portion of code, you are getting error, find Is this error coming due to any library attached.

Answer (score 0):

Compiling your application by defining particular compile SDK version is only required if you would want to use the features provided by that particular SDK version.

You can definitely compile with lower version and make it compatible for the higher version, but as said above you won't be able to use the new functionalities/features defined by higher version.

Comment: How can i compile with lower version and make it compatible for the higher version?

Comment: @user293171 why do you want to compile with lower version?

Comment: I want to compile with 21 to avoid these kind of errors and also be able to run in devices running 22 lollipop 5.1.