# Xamarin build ERROR : error APT0000: In <declare-styleable> ..., unable to find attribute

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I received a project from another developer. I setup my machine. VS-2017 with the required components was already configured.

Android SDK-Manager has the corresponding version installed. Project is configured to compile with `Android 7.1 (Nougat)`.

Starting the build I get one error

```
1>ERROR : error APT0000: In <declare-styleable> AppBarLayout, unable to find attribute android:keyboardNavigationCluster
```

It is unclear to me, were I need to set this information, or were this information is needed.

I rececked [ERROR: In  MenuView, unable to find attribute android:preserveIconSpacing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29248579/error-in-declare-styleable-menuview-unable-to-find-attribute-androidpreserv)
 and [Error:In  SherlockSpinner, unable to find attribute android:popupPromptView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29726125/errorin-declare-styleable-sherlockspinner-unable-to-find-attribute-androidp). Both articles don't help.

I rechecked the SDK-Tools, I deleted the folder `C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\Xamarin`.

As far as I understand the message there is an attribute missing, that needs to be set.

In a project file `Resource.designer.cs` I found

```
public const int AppBarLayout_android_keyboardNavigationCluster = 2;
```

The name seams to match exactly.

Can someone explain me this error?

Can someone explain how I get rid of it and how to fix similar problems in future?

Comment: I mentioned this already in my post. I didn't see any solution for me. What point I should try. (Even I think I checked all)...

Comment: Have you tried restarting `Visual Studio` ? What version of support libraries are you using?

Comment: Yes. Surely I tried a restart. Android Versions 25, 26, 27 are installed (and more).

Comment: I meant what versions of support libraries are you using, you may need to update that.

Comment: I updated all what is required and offered by the SDK-Manager.

Comment: Please refer to : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/105287/what-is-error-apt0000-cannot-find-attr-android-keyboardnavigationcluster-apt0000

Answer (score 8):

I had this error and after some research I just installed the Android OREO 8.0 SDK in the
[Android SDK Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DuD09.png) and than I select [Android Project > Properties > Application > Use latest Platform (Android 8.0 (Oreo))](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5eK5.png). And it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed it by setting the Target Android Version to API Level 26.

Answer (score 2):

You have to update the target of your project, It seems that the solution was created with a higher target `(Oreo API Level 26)`

Answer (score 0):

Thsi is what I did, I don't know what of the steps fixed the problems.

1. Uninstalled all Android SDKs with the SDK manager
2. Uninstalled the Xamarin components.

1.+2. Was done by uninstalling the App-Development features from VS-2017

3. Install Xamarin and current SDKs.

After this I was able to select "Use latest platform (Android 8.0 Oreo)" in the Android project section in the Solution.

This wasn't possible before. I just could select "Android 7.1 (Nougat)" and 8.0 didn't showed up (but was installed). Now the error is gone.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I'd moved from Enterprise to Professional and found that there was a mismatch in the Xamarin options (Tools -> Options -> Xamarin) and the android SDK location needed to be changed to "C:\Users\YourMum\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk".

Can't remember exactly what it was originally but think it was in Programs.