# Xamarin Forms Android Compile Error

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, visual-studio-mac

I'm trying to update my Xamarin Forms app to the latest Xamarin Forms and target the Android version against 7.1. After updating the build and target framework to 7.1 I'm getting the following compile time error:

/Users/austingrigg/Projects/ArtCloud/Droid/ERROR: Error APT0000: In  AppBarLayout, unable to find attribute android:keyboardNavigationCluster (APT0000) (ArtCloud.Droid)

I'm using Visual Studio for Mac (7.3), Xamarin Forms 2.5.0.121934, and Xamarin Support Libraries 25.4.0.2

Comment: [What about this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46974003/xamarin-build-error-error-apt0000-in-declare-styleable-unable-to-find)

Comment: @JoeLv Thanks, that's what I ended up doing.

Comment: So, does it work?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure ALL of your Nugets are the same version. Open up your packages.xml and double check, then do a full clean/rebuild and try to delete your bin/obj folders.

Comment: I did that, but I still got the same error. I ended up updating the project to target Android 8.0 and upgrade support libraries to match (26.1.0.1) then it compiles. I tried that same thing earlier and was getting a crash with a null reference exception, but that seems to be resolved now.